# Feature is visible in a layer but geometry is None in QGIS using Python

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

I am using the feature's geometry in a layer to get the centroid point of the polygon. One particular feature is visible in a TOC layer and also able to select a feature. But, while reading that feature's geometry it shows "NONE". And also, while checking the nodes using **"Node Vertex"**, it shows all the vertex of that polygon in vertex editor table.

How do I get the geometry of that feature?

Here I have attached a sample code and a error screenshot.

```
layer=self.iface.activeLayer()
for ft in layer.selectedFeatures():
    print ft.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you select those features beforehand or your code does it?

Comment: Which version of qgis are you using? I suggest you upgrade..

Comment: @Taras. I tried selecting the features in both ways. But still I didn't get it.

Comment: I am using Qgis 2.18.18 @ndawson

Comment: What happen if you try `getFeatures()` instead of `selectedFeatures()`?

Comment: @Taras. While using getFeatures() also the same issue occurs.

Comment: You should definitely upgrade to a newer qgis release and retest

Comment: @ ndawson As suggested, I tried the same in QGIS 3.2. Its working fine. Kindly suggest a way to get it on QGIS 2.18 or may I know why the issue occurs in 2.18.